# How to update brew if it is not updating?

Tags: macos, homebrew

I am trying to update my brew install. When I update using `brew update` it shows already up to date, however it is not.

Tried `brew doctor` as well. But it showed nothing.

Is **reinstalling** brew the only option left?

I am using **Mac OS Sierra**.

Comment: What makes you think it's not up to date? Have you upgraded from when Homebrew required sudo access? Reinstalling brew is quite simple, maybe that would be the cleanest way

Comment: @bensarz I have a 0.9.x version. The current version is 1.x.x. Most probably I will uninstall and reinstall.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea.

Comment: @bensarz Fixed it: cd $(brew --repo) && git fetch && git reset --hard origin/master && brew update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I found a solution. Unlucky me stumbled upon [this one](https://samoylov.tech/2016/09/01/homebrew-not-updating-since-august-2016/) I guess.

Used the same solution:

```
cd $(brew --repo) && git fetch && git reset --hard origin/master && brew update
```

Comment: Nice find! This is great!

Comment: Also, you might have to do a similar thing in the directory $(brew --repo homebrew/core). My problem was that I forgot that I forked and checkedout a different commit there. That broke updates.

Comment: @alexei that was it. Thanks.

Comment: Another useful one to try is `brew update-reset`